# Complex (ish) SQL join and count query

Tags: php, sql, join, count

I'm trying to create a simple poll function using php and sql.
I have three tables:

**Questions**

Which simply contains each question asked

question_id | question_text | created_at

**Answers**

Which contains each answer for each question

question_id | answer_id | answer_text

**Answered Questions**

Which records who has voted for each option

question_id | answer_id | user_ip

I'm trying to write a query which will return a single question (the most recent) along with all the possible answers to that question and finally a count of each answer to each question.  I know I will have to use a GROUP BY clause and possible LEFT OUTER JOIN, but the exact syntax is eluding me atm.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Why keeping `question_id` in the third table? `question_id` is defined by the `answer_id`.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Unless his primary key is composite (question_id, answer_id).

Comment: @Hosam Aly: you think that one answer can be applied to multiple questions?

Comment: @Quassnoi: No, but he might have configured the primary key to be composite, counting answer IDs for each question separately. (E.g. Q1 has answers A1, A2 and A3; Q2 has answers A1, and A2.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work on most DBMSs:

```
select q.question_id, question_text, a.answer_id, a.answer_text, count(user_ip)
  from questions q
 inner join answers a on (q.question_id = a.question_id)
  left join answered_questions aq on (a.question_id = aq.question_id
                                      and a.answer_id = aq.answer_id)
 where created_at = (select max(created_at)
                       from questions
                     )
 group by q.question_id, a.answer_id, q.question_text, a.answer_text
```

Comment: Your query doesnt account for cases where two questions were created at the same time - You should replace the subquery with WHERE q.question_id = (SELECT TOP 1 question_id FROM QUESTIONS ORDER BY created_at DESC)

Comment: Having two questions with the same `created_at` time would be a problem for the OP, as he should have a definite criteria for identifying *the most recent question* he asked for. Using `TOP` would not solve the problem, as 1) it would return an arbitrary record, and 2) it is not supported by all databases (e.g. MySQL and PostgreSQL use `LIMIT` instead).

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the closest so far to what I need.  However, it is returning two rows for each answer. eg:

What is your favourite colour?
blue
orange
red
blue
orange
red

Comment: @Dan: This should never happen, unless you have something incorrect in your data. We are grouping by both `question_id` and `answer_id`, so a single row in the table `answers` cannot appear twice. Is it possible that there is some duplication in your data?

Answer (score 2):

This is very similar to the logic in this article http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/.

Essentially you need a subquery which selects the single record / question you are interested in, as well as an outer query to select the information related to that record that you are interested in

(I could post another SQL statement to add to the nice collection that have already been posted, but I thought I'd try and shed some light onto how the other posted queries work)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're usnig `MySQL`:

```
SELECT  q.* ,
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    answered_questions aq
        WHERE   aq.answer_id = a.answer_id
                AND aq.question_id = q.question_id
        ) AS votes
FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    question
        ORDER BY
                created_at DESC
        LIMIT 1
        ) q
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        answers a
ON      a.question_id = q.question_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    questions.question_id,
    questions.question_text,
    answers.answer_id,
    answers.answer_text,
    COUNT(answered_questions.user_ip)
FROM
    questions,answers,
    answered_questions
WHERE
    questions.question_id=answers.question_id
    AND
    questions.question_id=
        (SELECT
            question_id
            FROM questions
            ORDER BY questions.created_at
            LIMIT 1
        )
    AND
    answered_questions.question_id=questions.question_id
GROUP BY
    questions.question_id
```

should work (although I haven't tested it).

Comment: That's much better. But this query would select the least recent question (as opposed to the most recent one as required by the OP).